# useState not updating , after using set outside of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

functional component - react js
I am running a process . I want to stop that process if user click on stop (stop button is on a diffrent component - Modal )

### process function on app.js looks like

```
 const [terminate, setterminate] = useState(false);

const process =()=>{

... some code (has no use of terminate or setterminate)
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){

     if(terminate){
         break
        }

      // api call
    }
} // process function ends

const stopProcess = ()=>{
       setterminate(true)
}

// called a modal and passes stopProcess as prop. and when click stop button in modal, that invoke stopProcess function. but for loop insite process function dont get break
```

### Modal.js

```
...

<button onClick={stopProcess}></ button >
...
```

everything works fine, except for does not breaks. function is invoked , tested by console.log("sdf")

### how do I break that foor loop ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but I suspect the root cause is that you don't know state changes are asynchronous. Your terminate variable won't change until the next render. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) for more information on that.

Comment: from what I understood is you are asking how to pass the state to the modal component. You will have to pass that as a prop. Let me if I understood that right. Ill give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

(clousers and working of useState (async ) and how it is update. (please read that first))
to get immediately value of useState

```
let temp_terminate=false;
  setterminateProcess((state)=>{
        temp_terminate=state;
        return state;
      })
```